# react redux how can I pass initialstate with functions?

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to check the Key, if the key exists then I want to set the loggedIn in the initalstate to true. How can I do it? I get no error but my code not working.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import getSecureKey from '../../../utilies/getSecureKey';

const initialState = {
  process: false,
  loggedIn: getSecureKey().then(res => res).catch(e => e),
  message: '',
  error: '',
};
```

```
import * as SecureStore from 'expo-secure-store';

const getSecureKey = async () => {
  const key = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('jwt');
  return key != '' ? true : false
};

export default getSecureKey;
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use asynchronous code in your `initialState`.  What this actually does is set your `state.loggedIn` property to a `Promise`, so you should be getting warnings from redux-toolkit about storing non-serializable values in state.

It takes a moment for the `getSecureKey()` function to resolve.  But the `createStore`/`configureStore` function is synchronous and cannot wait for the resolution.

You have two options.

1. You can wait for `getSecureKey()` to resolve *before* creating the store.  Your entire app can't really do anything until the store is created to you would have to render a loading screen instead, similar to what redux-persist does with the [`PersistGate`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/HEAD/docs/PersistGate.md) component.  I don't recommend this.
2. You can `dispatch` an action to update the `loggedIn` state after the `getSecureKey()` function has finished resolving.  You could set the initial value of `state.loggedIn` to `false`, but I actually recommend using `null` or `undefined` as a third option which tells you that you don't know yet whether the user is logged in or not.  You can use a hook to handle the `dispatch` from your top-level `App` component.  You can use an [async thunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) as an action creator to automatically handle errors.

Initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  process: false,
  loggedIn: null,
  message: '',
  error: '',
};
```

Action creator:

```
export const getInitialKey = createAsyncThunk(
  "someActionName",
  async () => {
    return await getSecureKey();
  }
)
```

In your slice:

```
extraReducers: {
  [getInitialKey.fulfilled]: (state, action) => {
    state.loggedIn = action.payload;
  },
  [getInitialKey.rejected]: (state, action) => {
    state.loggedIn = false;
  }
}
```

Auto-dispatch with hook:

```
const useGetSecureKey = () => {
  // we know that a key was received if the state isn't null
  const didAttempt = useSelector(state => state.mySlice.loggedIn !== null);

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  // dispatches when the state is null
  // you could also use an empty dependency array and it's basically the same
  useEffect( () => {
    if ( ! didAttempt ) {
      dispatch(getInitialKey());
    }
  }, [didAttempt, dispatch]);
}
```

Comment: I thank you for your answers. I dont use redux thunk, I use redux saga. I am sorry that I dont tell it to you.

Comment: You can do something similar with saga, but it's easier with thunk.

Comment: I know it's an old question, but why don't you recommend the first approach? Because of the loading screen?